Google Sheets formula INDERECT on range
I have 3 team tabs: Team A, Team B, Team C.
I have technical tab: Teams with prev tabs names.
I would like to create compare/summary tab: Comparing
Formula in Comparing Tab is:
=QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(INDIRECT(SORT(Teams!A2:A & "!D10"))), "select Col1 order by Col1 desc", 1)

which will take cells D10 from each tab and display a list in descending order. Preferably with the name of the tab
It gives the error "Syntax error" and does not output anything - please help
I guess =INDERECT(Teams!A2:A & "!D10") should return array of numbers - but its return one number


Here's one approach you may test out:
=sort(map(tocol(Teams!A2:A,1),lambda(Σ,{Σ,indirect(Σ&"!D10")})),2,)

